# Asp RequiredFieldValidator invalid event on client side

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I want to show a loading message during each post on my asp website. For that, I show the loader in jQuery on submit event of the main form and I hide it on document ready event. But i have a problem, i check inputs with RequiredFieldValidator and when verification failed, the submit event still fired. So my loader appears but it never disappears cause document ready is never fired.

can anyone please help me to find a way to know if the verification passed before showing the loader ?

Comment: do you want to show the loader on page loading ?

Comment: Yes, but not only. I also want it on each postback.

Comment: you can show loading every time when page loads by css.
and hide it when  page loaded completely. 
I do the same thing by css. if you want I can post the code.

Comment: Yes please, it will help me

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following `style script` for showing loading on full page:

```
 #pageloaddiv {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 9999;
            background: url('/Areas/Admin/Content/Images/pageloader.gif') no-repeat center center;
            background-color: #fff;
            opacity: 0.8;
        }
```

In `body` area use below div:

```
<div id="pageloaddiv"></div>
```

When the page loaded completely we have to use following script, for hiding the loading `div`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">             
        $(window).load(function () {
             $("#pageloaddiv").fadeOut(2000);
         });
    </script>
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this to stop the submit from firing

```
event.preventDefault();
```

My button looks something like this

```
              $( "#submitform" )
                    .button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-search" }})
                    .click(function(event) {
                       $(this).button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-custom" }})
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("#myformid").submit();
                                     return true;
                     });
```

The ui-icon-custom is just a revolving gif attached to the button

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer in asp documentation : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside

There is an Client Side Api with only 4 objects and one is Page_IsValid. This boolean is always kept up to date by validation script and it indicates whether the page is currently valid.

So, i just have to check if this boolean is set to true before showing the loader.